# QGIS GeoPDF Export - change field that appears top in pdf model tree

Tags: qgis, geopdf

I am exporting a map layout to GeoPDF using QGIS.

Is there a way to change/choose the layer field that gets used in the pdf model tree as the display field for each record? I have attached a screenshot that shows the 'PSOL Category' field has been used as the display field in the model tree, whereas I would like it to the the 'Asset Number' field.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change the field name by opening the attribute table in `Form view`, and in the `Expression` field located at the top left corner choose "Asset Number" field.

In the following example I want to switch from "Name" field to "Id" field:

[image]

Now you can export to GeoPDF and the "Id" field will be used.

Using "Name" field in GeoPDF:

[image]

Using "Id" field in GeoPDF:

[image]

Comment: This is a good way to rename fields without editing the exported pdf.

Comment: Thanks, can confirm this worked for me.